# Concatenating views in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference, slice

Indexing [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array through slices/indexes creates a view that is lightweight (doesn't copy data) and allows assigning to elements of original array. I.e.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a[2:4] = [6, 7]
print(a)
# [1 2 6 7 5]
```

But how about multiple views, how do I concatenate them to create a bigger view that still assigns to original first array. E.g. for imaginary function `concatenate_views(...)`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
concatenate_views((a[1:3], a[4:6], a[7:9])) = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
print(a)
# should print [1 11 12 4 13 14 7 15 16 10]
```

Of course, I can create a list of indexes for each view that it views to, just by converting slices to indexes and then concatenating these indexes. This way I'll get all indexes of concatenated views and can use these indexes to create a combined view. But this is not what I want. I want NumPy to keep the notion of slices representation, because all slices can be very long and it will be inefficient to convert and store these slices as indexes. I want NumPy to be aware of underlying slices of all concatenated views to make internally just simple looping of slices ranges.

Also would be nice to generalize the problem. Not only concatenate views, but also allow to form any arbitrary tree of slicing/indexing operations, e.g. concatenate views, then apply some slicing, then indexing, then slicing, then concatenate again. Also N-dimensional slicing/indexing. I.e. all fancy stuff that can be done with single un-concatenated view.

The main point of concatenated views is only efficiency. Of cause we can represent any view or slicing operation by N-D array of integer indexes (coordinates, like meshgrid) and then can use this array to make a view of source array. But if numpy can keep a notion of source set of slices instead of array of integers, then first it will be lightweight (much less memory consumption), second instead of reading indexes from memory numpy internally can loop (iterate) through each slice more efficiently in `C++` loops.

By having concatenated view I wanted to be able to apply any numpy operation like `np.mean(...)` to the combined view in efficient way.

Full procedure of concatenating views of N-D slicing based on 2D example is described down below:

```
    1 Step described below:
    
    2D array slicing using 3 slices for each axis
    
    a,b,c - sizes of "slices" along axis 0
    d,e,f - sizes of "slices" along axis 1
    
    Each "slice" - is either slice(start, stop, step) or 1D array of integer indexes
            
      d e f
     .......
    a.0.1.2.
     .......
    b.3.4.5.
     .......
    c.6.7.8.
     .......

    Above 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 mean not a single integer but some 2D sub-array.
    Dots (`.`) also mean some 2D sub-arrays.
    
    Sub-views shapes:
    0:(a, d), 1:(a, e), 2:(a, f)
    3:(b, d), 4:(b, e), 5:(b, f)
    6:(c, d), 7:(c, e), 8:(c, f)

    Final aggregated (concatenated) view shape:
    ((a + b + c), (d + e + f))
    containing 2D array
    012
    345
    678
    
    There can be more than one Steps, each next Step applies new sequence of slicing
    to the final view obtained on previous Step. Each Step has different set of sizes
    of slices and different amount of slices per each dimension.
    In general each next Step reduces number of total elements, except the case
    when slices or indexes overlap then you may get more elements but with duplicates.
```

Comment: Would those always be equal intervaled slices?

Comment: @Divakar It could simplify solution of cause. But I want some generic function. That allows to form any Tree of slicing. I.e. apply slices to slices. Apply indexing to slices, etc. Same fancy stuff as can be done with single un-concatenated view. Also N-D slicing.

Comment: Then, simply create a boolean mask initialized as zeros and assign True for those slices iteratively. Finally do `a[mask] = new_values`.

Comment: In my question above I mention this case saying that I really want NumPy to keep notion of source slicing instead of conversion to plain indexes or bools, because arrays could be very huge and indexes not only consume lots of memory but also slow to process. If NumPy keeps original slicing then internally it can just organize maybe-recursive loops over slice ranges. So slices allow fast and lightweight algorithms inside NumPy.

Comment: Masking is not as bad as integer indexing and boolean masks has 1/8th memory overhead as compared to an equal length int array. Don't just jump to conclusion(s), without trying out what works for your case. Finally, if you have long slices, you might want to simply iterate and assign.

Comment: @Divakar bools can be used for some cases, especially for very dense indexing/slicing. But if slices are really sparse, like having step of 100 or more then bools iterating will be very inefficient. Probably the optimal solution lies somewhere in combination of several methods chosen for each case differently.

Comment: Read more about the basics of how arrays are stored - shape, strides and data buffer (and dtype).  A view shares the data buffer, but has its own shape and strides.  Is your complex slice(s) representable that way?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, basically slicing a view repeatedly by several slicing operations reduces more and more this view, but still it is a view representable, as shape plus stride. If you have one slice (start0, stop0, step0) and apply second one to it (start1, stop1, step1) then new slice will be also alway representable by some (start2, stop2, step2) slicing viewing into original first array.

Comment: @hpaulj Basically I really want to have some very generic and very fast solution for N-d slicing and indexing in arbitrary way. There are two main purposes - first to be very efficient like in C++, speed wise and memory wise. Secondary to be very flexible, meaning to have all possible ways of applying (maybe super-position) of slices and indexes. Maybe I just need to come up with C++ or Cython or Numba generic solution instead of waiting to finding out how to implement this in current numpy functions.

Comment: @hpaulj So superposition of any slicing is representable using sub-array shape + striding. But concatenation of slicing is not. It needs to keep a list of slices in general. So probably numpy may not have any concatenation of views.

Comment: Concatenate makes a new array with its own copy of the data (regardless of what the source arrays are)

Comment: Let me know if my answer addresses your concern

Comment: @hpaulj. Do you think it's worth making a PR for the function I wrote, after some improvements? Specifically, I'm thinking of adding a `copy=True` flag to concatenate/append, which would avoid copying data if possible when set to `False`.

Comment: @Divakar. Could you take a look and let me know if you think my answer is worth productionizing and making a PR for? This is a feature I've wanted to have for a while, but never bothered to work out the details for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only concatenate views if they are contiguous in terms of dtypes, strides and offsets. Here is one way to check. This way is likely incomplete, but it illustrates the gist of it. Basically, if the views share a base, and the strides and offsets are aligned so that they are on the same grid, you can concatenate.

In the spirit of TDD, I will work with the following example:

```
x = np.arange(24).reshape(4, 6)
```

We (or at least I) want the following to be concatenatable:

```
a, b = x[:, :4], x[:, 4:]        # Basic case
a, b = x[:, :4:2], x[:, 4::2]    # Strided
a, b = x[:, :4:2], x[:, 2::2]    # Strided overlapping
a, b = x[1:2, 1:4], x[2:4, 1:4]  # Stacked

# Completely reshaped:
a, b = x.ravel()[:12].reshape(3, 4), x.ravel()[12:].reshape(3, 4)
# Equivalent to
a, b = x[:2, :].reshape(3, 4), x[2:, :].reshape(3, 4)
```

We do **not** want the following to be concatenatable:

```
a, b = x, np.arange(12).reshape(2, 6)   # Buffer mismatch
a, b = x[0, :].view(np.uint), x[1:, :]  # Dtype mismatch
a, b = x[:, ::2], x[:, ::3]             # Stride mismatch
a, b = x[:, :4], x[:, 4::2]             # Stride mismatch
a, b = x[:, :3], x[:, 4:]               # Overlap mismatch
a, b = x[:, :4:2], x[:, 3::2]           # Overlap mismatch
a, b = x[:-1, :-1], x[1:, 1:]           # Overlap mismatch
a, b = x[:-1, :4], x[:, 4:]             # Shape mismatch
```

The following could be interpreted as concatenatable, but won't be in this case:

```
a, b = x, x[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

The idea is that everything (dtype, strides, offsets) has to match exactly. Only one axis offset is allowed to be different between the views, as long as it is no more than one stride away from the edge of the other view. The only possible exception is when one view is fully contained in another, but we will ignore this scenario here. Generalizing to multiple dimensions should be pretty simple if we use array operations on the offsets and strides.

```
def cat_slices(a, b):
    if a.base is not b.base:
        raise ValueError('Buffer mismatch')
    if a.dtype != b.dtype:  # I don't thing you can use `is` here in general
        raise ValueError('Dtype mismatch')

    sa = np.array(a.strides)
    sb = np.array(b.strides)

    if (sa != sb).any():
        raise ValueError('Stride mismatch')

    oa = np.byte_bounds(a)[0]
    ob = np.byte_bounds(b)[0]

    if oa > ob:
        a, b = b, a
        oa, ob = ob, oa

    offset = ob - oa

    # Check if you can get to `b` from a by moving along exactly one axis
    # This part works consistently for arrays with internal overlap
    div = np.zeros_like(sa)
    mod = np.ones_like(sa)  # Use ones to auto-flag divide-by zero
    np.divmod(offset, sa, where=sa.astype(bool), out=(div, mod))

    zeros = np.flatnonzero((mod == 0) & (div >= 0) & (div <= a.shape))

    if not zeros.size:
        raise ValueError('Overlap mismatch')

    axis = zeros[0]

    check_shape = np.equal(a.shape, b.shape)
    check_shape[axis] = True

    if not check_shape.all():
        raise ValueError('Shape mismatch')

    shape = list(a.shape)
    shape[axis] = b.shape[axis] + div[axis]

    start = np.byte_bounds(a)[0] - np.byte_bounds(a.base)[0]

    return np.ndarray(shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=a.base, offset=start, strides=a.strides)
```

Some things that this function does not handle:

- Merging flags
- Broadcasting
- Handling arrays that are fully contained within each other but with multi-axis offsets
- Negative strides

You can, however, check that it returns the expected views (and errors) for all the cases shown above. In a more production-y version, I could envision this enhancing `np.concatenate`, so for failed cases, it would just copy data instead of raising an error.

Comment: Very nice piece of code. Definitely something like this should be included in `numpy` library, at least into some util sub-dir. For this to work numpy doesn't need to introduce anything new in its underlying representation. But this solves my task only partially, just sub-case of compatible views. I already probably understood that my task is unsolvable in general form. What I really wanted to solve is next even more general thing - suppose we have any huge Tree of mix of slicing/indexing, slicing can be applied second time to slicing+indexes, etc.

Comment: @Arty. Just like any tree, you would chain the operations. Unless you show a concrete example, it's hard to discuss.

Comment: So I want this Tree to be remembered somewhere by numpy as a property of some Complex-View, so that later in any operation that needs to iterate through all elements of this view just does nested looping over this Tree elements and thus iterates through original array's elements, without the need to convert this Tree to plain integer indexes array. Iterating over slicing Tree might be or might be not more efficient, although in many cases it may be much more efficient than by converted indexes array, also memor conserving.

Comment: It looks like you want something like this, but in tensorflow

Comment: First, operations are not always chainable, imagine applying some aggregating function, like computing mean. You have to compute mean for every slice in Tree your self and combine this means by some formula manually. Instead of numpy doing it for you all correctly. Secondly your tree may be huge in total and have very tiny elements like slices with few elements in range or several integer indexes. Then iterating by yourself in pure Python loops will be inefficient compared to numpy's C++.

Comment: @Arty. Again, a concrete example, perhaps in another question, would give us something to discuss. Also, numpy is mostly C, not C++.

Comment: And also, you're saying that I can just loop over slices. Indeed I can do many things manually and implement my wrapper function to do all that. But that is exactly what was my question about, about the best Implementing solution for my task, if we can envent something that can be even included in numpy. Like you did above, that could go into real numpy's util sub-directory for production.

Comment: @Arty. I still don't have a clear idea of what you have in mind. Between this function, normal indexing, and ufuncs, you can do quite a bit of very efficient computing if you're careful. I don't have a picture of the tree you're referring to that would require this additional processing.

Comment: I've just created [this text file](https://pastebin.com/raw/i7T271Tb) with simple example and description how N-D (2D in my example) slicing looks like and what concatenation mean. That's basically what I want to achieve in my question's solution. Per each dimension there can be several slices and/or indexes.

Comment: So for that kind of slicing described in link above I want to create final lightweight view, then when any operation (like np.mean()) is applied to this view internally numpy would do looping over this sub-views' slices and apply final operation (np.mean). Of cause whole final view can be represented as array of indexes, but my question was about the ability for numpy to keep/iterate real slices instead of huge arrays of integer indexes.

Comment: @Arty. Perhaps you would care to ask another question?

Comment: I was totally sure that I've upvoted your answer, at least I meant to, did this now. I included text linked above into my question, at the very end. Please read it. Basically it explains what I meant in my question by `Concatenating Views`. But as I understood my question should be really answered something like this `There is no built-in support for concatenating views in numpy, something that I want can't be achieved in very general form.` Only for some specific cases like you implemented above it can be achieved. So I'll probably wait a bit and accept your answer with checkbox

Comment: @Arty. Got it. I'll read the text when I get home. I can't access the site it's posted on right now. The main thing to keep in mind is that views can only exists when the stides along each axis don't change. If your situation is different, you're looking for something else. It's likely that carefully managing in-place operations on different slices will satisfy most needs.

Comment: @Arty. Sorry, I'm slow. I just saw the updated question. I suggest that you ask another question about that. You've altered the meaning of the original question quite a bit by adding that. Also, in the new question, I suggest you work through a concrete example, "by hand" if neccessary, on a suitably sized array. I am having some trouble parsing through the prose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate slice objects and assign back to the indexed array:

```
a[np.r_[1:3, 4:6, 7:9]] = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

print(a)
array([ 1, 11, 12,  4, 13, 14,  7, 15, 16, 10])
```

**Update**

Based on your update, I think you might want something like:

```
from itertools import islice

it = iter([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
for s in slice(1,3), slice(4,6), slice(7,9):
    a[s] = list(islice(it, s.stop-s.start))

print(a)
array([ 1, 11, 12,  4, 13, 14,  7, 15, 16, 10])
```

Comment: I've updated my question with large paragraph saying that I want to not convert slices to indexes for efficiency, so that numpy keeps knowledge of underlying slicing and creates simple internal looping over source slicing ranges.

Comment: Also is it possible to make tree of slicing? I.e. apply slicing of slices. Also N-D slicing. Etc. all fancy stuff that can be used with regular un-concatenated view.

Comment: Updated @arty Let me know if this is what you're after

Comment: Yes, that's a nice approach, basically if I have a tree of slicing/indexing operations then I can manually apply this slicing one by one. Still this can be inefficient when also using indexing combined with slicing, not just slicing alone. Also algorithm should take into account slicing of slices somehow.

Comment: @Arty. All the things you want are encoded in a single operation: combining two views into another view. That view is then an array in its own right that you can do whatever you want to: reshape, index, or combine with an additional slice view.